# How can I make an object reference?

Tags: jquery, math, random

```
var $playerChoice1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*5+1));
var $playerChoice2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*(10-6+1)+6));

var $playmaking1 = $player+$playerChoice1.playmaking;
var $playmaking2 = $player+$playerChoice2.playmaking;
var $rebounding1 = $player+$playerChoice1.rebounding;
var $rebounding2 = $player+$playerChoice2.rebounding;
```

I'd like to get values from randomly chosen $player objects ($player1, $player2, .., $player9, $player10). First player is chosen from 1 to 5 and the other from 6 to 10. My code doesn't work (of course). How should I deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var players = [...]; // ten players

var $playerChoice1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5));     // range [0, 4]
var $playerChoice2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5 + 5)); // range [5, 9]

var $playmaking1 = players[$playerChoice1].playmaking;
var $playmaking2 = players[$playerChoice2].playmaking;
```